# upload_to attribute is being overwritten by unknown source

Tags: python, django, django-models

upload_to attribute is being overwritten and I have no idea what's causing this, instead of uploading a file I'm getting a SuspiciousFileOperation exception. The base path component stated in the exception is correct but joined path is not correct as it should be just 'img/posts'.

**models.py**

```
thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='img/posts')
```

**Exception value**

```
The joined path (/media/tb1.jpg) is located outside of the base path component (/home/user/Documents/project/project/media)
```

Comment: Do you already set media related variable in `settings.py` ?

Comment: ```MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')``` It worked before I have used it for a week maybe 6-7 rows added to database and suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Are you added file path or file in db?

Comment: `upload_to may also be a callable, such as a function`
You may define a function and set breakpoint into

Comment: File path, it looks like this after query: ```img/posts/filename.jpeg```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: did you set `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` too?

Comment: Still doesn't work, same issue

Comment: Yes, it's set to ```/media/```

Comment: in `urls.py` also you set media url properly?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this:


```urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.NewsPostListView.as_view(), name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)```

Comment: Ok, it's also look good

Comment: Yeah, as I said it used to work perfectly fine until yesterday without me changing anything. It's really weird and I have no idea what's causing this.

Comment: When you add data directly in the db at that time you pass a file of path to the file field, right?

Comment: Yes, the entry in the database looks like this: ```img/posts/filename.jpeg```. There are already some paths stored in the database.

Comment: If your data is not too much important then try to delete all data from table and and rerun your site.

Comment: Thanks for your time, will try that.

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine :)